# MySQL how to get avg of values into specific range

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the following table data:

```
value
1
5
10.5
12
36
```

I want to map these values into:

```
range      avg
0-21       (1 + 5 + 10.5 + 12) / 4
21.001-34  0
34.001-64  36
64 +       0
```

Basically map each value to ranges and calculate the avg of all values in each range.

I tried to do:

```
select 
case
when avggeneral between 0 and 21 then ' 0-21'
when avggeneral between 21.00001 and 34 then ' 21-34'
when avggeneral between 34.00001 and 64 then ' 34-64'
else '64+'
end as 'range',
AVG(*) as 'avg'
from table
```

but this doesn't work... I don't know how to make the static ranges...

How can I do that in MySQL?

Methology should be:
1. Map values into these groups ( 0-21, 21-34 etc..)
2. calulate AVG in each group.

Desired output for above example is this:

```
range      avg
0-21       7.125
21.001-34  0
34.001-64  36
64 +       0
```

The `range` column is static. Always with 5 rows.
The `avg` column is dynamic.. the values there are the actual AVGs of `value` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a list of ranges using `UNION ALL` and `LEFT JOIN` with it:

```
SELECT CONCAT(IFNULL(ranges.min, '∞'), '-', IFNULL(ranges.max, '∞')) AS `range`, avg(value) AS avg
FROM (
    SELECT 0 AS min, 21 AS max UNION ALL
    SELECT 21, 34 UNION ALL
    SELECT 34, 64 UNION ALL
    SELECT 64, NULL
) AS ranges
LEFT JOIN t ON (ranges.min IS NULL OR value >= ranges.min) AND
               (ranges.max IS NULL OR value <  ranges.max)
GROUP BY ranges.min, ranges.max
```

Note that the above query will put `20.9999` inside `[0-21)` and `21.0000` inside `[21-34)` range.

Comment: This doesn't work. It generate one row.. I'll edit to explain

Comment: @Luis see revised answer.

Comment: Was just typing something very similar. You should use `COALESCE(AVG(value),0)` to remove `NULL` values from the output though

Comment: Where does my table input comes in?

Comment: @Luis in `LEFT JOIN t` replace `t` with your table name

Answer (score 3):

You can use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to get the desired result like below :

```
select '0-21' as Range1, coalesce(avg(avggeneral),0) as AVG from Table1
where avggeneral > 0 and avggeneral <= 21
union
select '21-34' as Range1, coalesce(avg(avggeneral),0) as AVG from Table1
where avggeneral > 21 and avggeneral <= 34
union
select '34-64' as Range1, coalesce(avg(avggeneral),0) as AVG from Table1
where avggeneral > 34 and avggeneral <= 64
union
select '64+' as Range1, coalesce(avg(avggeneral),0) as AVG from Table1
where avggeneral > 64
```

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5ad65/20)

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use those decimals.
Because for example, if the "value" equals 21, then the `CASE` would already return the 0-21 range before evaluating the next `WHEN`.

But you still need to group on the range.

And to return all the ranges, whether or not they are missing, you could left join to a sub-query with the ranges.

```
SELECT Ranges.`range`, COALESCE(AVG(Q.`value`), 0) as `avg`
FROM
(
  SELECT 0 as `class`, ' 0-21' as `range`
  UNION ALL SELECT 21, '21-34'
  UNION ALL SELECT 34, '34-64'
  UNION ALL SELECT 64, '64+'
) Ranges
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
   `value`,
   case
   when `value` between  0 and 21 then 0
   when `value` between 21 and 34 then 21
   when `value` between 34 and 64 then 34
   when `value` > 64 then 64
   end as rangeclass
  FROM test
) Q ON Q.rangeclass = Ranges.`class`
GROUP BY Ranges.`class`, Ranges.`range`
ORDER BY Ranges.`class`
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6ca262ed0837714df89d4f314598cd0)*

Comment: It doesn't work.. check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'range, AVG(value) as avg

Comment: @Luis Well, it worked when I used an actual table name. But indeed it was wrong in a way because it assumed that all ranges would be in the data.  Now that's fixed with a left join to a sub-query with the ranges.